# HTTPS BrilliantRetail checkout page not loading stylesheets

Tags: checkout, secure, brilliantretail

I am using the BrilliantRetail e-commerce extension with ExpressionEngine and there is an option to serve up the checkout page using the HTTPS protocol. This is working correctly, however, my HTTPS pages do not show the proper layout because the CSS files are not being served through HTTPS. If I use the inspect window to edit the HTML and change the CSS paths to HTTPS it works fine.

Anyone know how I can resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, the problem was resolved by removing the protocol from the site URL in the general settings menu.

`http://mysite.com` became `//mysite.com` and now all of the assets are being delivered through the correct protocol depending on what section of the site you are on.

Comment: great find. i was going to suggest that as CDNS do that same thing, glad you worked it out yourself!